# Upgrade postgresql 9.2 to 9.6

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I want to upgrade 15TB of PostgreSQL running on 9.2 to 9.6, but as of I know we have to rebuild the slave after upgrade from 9.2 to 9.6, I did same way some of our database with smaller size , but as this is very big database slave rebuild take more than 2 days, application team are not ready without slave for 2 days ,

does any body have any solution for this?

it would be a great help.

Comment: How do you rebuild the slave? `pg_basebackup` should be able to transfer 15TB in less then two days provided there is a fast network between the two servers

Comment: pg_basebackup takes 3 days to rebuild

Comment: we have streaming replication setup, postgres doesnt support lower to upper version upgrade when in streaming replication mode , so when i upgrade the master i have to rebuild the slaves and slave rebuild takes 3 days,which is not affordable and at a time we need one slave and one master ready ,Is there anyway that we dont have to rebuild slaves ,using streaming replication. 2.To build logical replication we thought of using slony but since slony has limitation that it does not automatically replicate •BLOBS),DDL users and roles and our application have continuous create commands ,so no slony.

Comment: `pg_basebackup` essentially copies the data directory over the network with the least overhead possible. With a 1000 Mbps network this should not take longer then 1.5 days. Did you try `rsync` to copy the data directory? Maybe that is faster.

Comment: is there any way not to rebuild the slave after the upgrade from 9.2 to 9.6?

Comment: x-posted to https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/184556/7788